# How does the haskell stack tool detect dirtiness of files?

Tags: haskell-stack

I am developing a Haskell project with stack that produces a binary with static assets embedded into the executable (e.g. images). This is done via Template Haskell - I have a module called `Static` that calls a TH function that reads files in a directory and embeds it.

When the static assets are updated I want the build process to embed the updated files into the binary. I was attempting to achieve this by running `touch Static.hs; stack build` i.e. update the timestamp of the haskell source file that calls the TH and then build. However, this does not cause stack to think that the file needs to be rebuilt.

How does stack (or perhaps the underlying cabal tool) detect if a source file needs to be rebuilt, and is there a recommended way to solve my problem described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [qAddDependentFile](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.3/template-haskell-2.12.0.0/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#v:qAddDependentFile) in your TemplateHaskell.  It tells GHC that the module depends on an extra file.  Stack also uses that information from GHC to be aware that the package depends on the extra file.  The [file-embed](https://www.stackage.org/package/file-embed) package makes it easy to embed a file and it handles this detail for you.